# Filter products by categories using Rails & AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I need to create a page that will display products by chosen filters. For simplicity I will use product categories as filters.

The page should have 2 areas:

1. Where products are displayed.
2. Where categories are displayed and a 'Clear All' button.

**Scenario:**

User visits the index page, all products are displayed.
User clicks the 'Home category' and gets all the products that belong to this category. Then he clicks on the 'Shoes category' and now he sees all the products that belong to both categories ('Home category' or 'Shoes category'). User clicks on the 'Clear All' button (in order to reset the chosen categories), now all the products from all the categories are displayed.

## My Code:

My models Product, Category, and join table causes_products.

**Category**

`class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end`

**Products**

`class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end`

**Products Controller:**

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products = Product.all
    @categories = Category.all
  end
  def from_category
    @products = Product.joins(:categories).where(categories: { id: params[:cat_id] })
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

**products/index.html.erb:**

```
<div class="grid">
  <%= render 'sidebar_menu' %>
  <%= render partial: 'product_grid', locals: { products: @products} %>
</div>
```

**products/_sidebar_menu.html.erb:**

```
<% @categories.each do | cat | %>
<%= link_to cat.name, fetch_products_path(:cat_id => cat.id), :remote => true %>
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
get "/fetch_products" => 'products#from_category', as: 'fetch_products'
```

**products/_products_grid.html.erb:**

```
<div id="products_grid">
  <%= render partial: 'products_list', locals: { products: products } %>
</div>
```

**products/_products_list.html.erb:**

```
<% products.each do |product| %>
    <div class="product_box">
      product.name
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**products/from_category.js.erb:**

```
$("#products_grid").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'products_list', locals: { products: @selected } ) %>");
```

**The code works great only for one chosen category, but I would like it to be able to filter two or more categories as well. What changes do I need to make?**

Thanks.

Thank you [@max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/544825/max) and [@Jeffrey M Castro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6186921/jeffrey-m-castro) for helping me with my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676443/rails-ajax-display-products-by-chosen-filters).

Thanks to sebastialonso for his article "[How to partials & AJAX, dead easy](https://coderwall.com/p/kqb3xq/rails-4-how-to-partials-ajax-dead-easy)".

Answer (score 0):

For your ajax method, here is what you can use:

```
def from_category
  category_ids = params[:cat_ids]
  @products = Product.joins(:categories).where("categories.id IN (?)", category_ids)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

To get the `params[:cat_ids]` from your form, see:
[Best way to get all selected checkboxes VALUES in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766044/best-way-to-get-all-selected-checkboxes-values-in-jquery)
or
https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Comment: can you please be more specific? I tried to implement what you recommended, the problem is that when I make the second click on the category (choose the second filter) it resets my previous choice. Thanks.

Comment: using rails debugger or binding.pry, check the parameters being sent to the controller each time you click on the checkboxes. (say for example you pressed 2 checkboxes, you should have params[:cat_ids] = ["1","2"], 1 and 2 being the ids or values of the categories in the checkboxes. From there you can filter the products.

Comment: What happen to params is: after the first click [:cat_ids] = ["1"] after the second click [:cat_ids] = ["2"]. What should I do to keep the value between the clicks instead of new assign every time?

Comment: well this means that your javascript for "getting" ALL the checked boxes is incorrect. If you checked only 1,then its correct to have ["1"] or ["2"], but if you checked both, it should be ["1", "2"]. See the link above in my answer, which gets all checked checkboxes.

Comment: Oh I didn't use check boxes should I?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I thought you said you were using them. You can use checkboxes, or multiselect dropdowns to get multiple categories passed