# Drop down filter to sort products by category on index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, associations

I am fairly new to rails and am building an online store. I currently have a products model and a categories model with the association: Products belong_to a category and a Category has_many products. I would like shoppers to have the ability to select a category in a drop down and the products on the index page will display only items in that category.

I was able to get a drop down to show all of the categories using a form_tag but when I select on a category the index page does not filter to show just that category.

Products index.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag('products', :remote => true) do %>
  <%= select_tag "category", options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, "id", "name"),  { :include_blank => true , :class => "product_select"} %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Filter' %>
<% end %>
```

Products controller:

```
  def index
    if Product.all.collect == (params[:category])
        @products= Product.send(params[:category])   
    else
        @products = Product.order(:title)   
    end 

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # index.html.erb
        format.js # index.js.erb
        format.json { render json: @products } 
      end  
  end
```

application.js:

```
$(document).ready ->   $(".product_select").on "change", ->
    $.ajax
      url: "/products"
      type: "GET"
      dataType: "script"
      data:
        dept_type: $(".product_select").val()
```

Thanks in advance for any help, let me know if any more information is needed.

Comment: I think your code always goes on your **else** condition on the index

Comment: you can get some inputs from the OP's code in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676443/rails-ajax-display-products-by-chosen-filters/36712930#36712930

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can call the DB from your view like that(I don't think so).  If you can do it you shouldn't.

Change Category.all

here

```
<%= select_tag "category", options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, "id", "name"),  { :include_blank => true , :class => "product_select"} %>
```

to @categories and set it in your controller.

what is the value of

```
 $(".product_select").val()
```

Also you may want a Many to many relationship for products and categories.  What happens when you want one product to be in 2 different categories?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with the ajax request on change of the value in the category dropdown.

1. on the div for the products index page, the part that displays the products add an ID to that div (say `products_div`).
   **sample code (_products_list.html.erb)**

   ```
   <div id="products_div">
     <%= @products.each do |product| %>
     # bla bla bla display product attributes
   </div>
   ```
2. then on your controller for index, you should update it to use the data from the ajax request
   **sample code (products_controller)**

   ```
   if params[:dept_type].present?  
     @products = Product.where(dept_id: params[:dept_type])  
   else  
     @products = Product.all  
   end
   ```
3. then on the view file, `products.js.erb`, replace the content of the `products_div`
   **sample code (index.js.erb)**

   ```
   $("#products_div").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'products_list', locals: { products: @products } ) %>");
   ```

The code in #3 will replace the contents of the products_div with the new @products which you filtered on change of the category dropdown

Comment: Thanks for the response. Would the code in #3 go into the products index.html.erb file or should I create a new file named products.js.erb in the products view folder?

Comment: if you expect a format.js response in your controller, you should create the .js.erb file in the views